# Show messages with JQuery and C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

my goal is to implement a message system on web site ( i mean users can send message one to another). Each message has only one button which actually close the message and update the db that that specific message has been read.

Some of my main requirments are :

- page should not be reloaded after closing each messaging
- when user close read message, new message will appear (till user has no new message)

The way i though to do it is aspx (c# code behind) which will prepare message details in divs or such, jquery which will show it in popup way (or another beutifull way it can :) ), and ajax which will allow me to update DB on each close button click (which message has been read).

Is there any jquery components which able to present message on screen (able to run with div inside div) and run AJAX code when closed ?

Highly interesting in code example but usefull link will apreatiated as well :)

Comment: have you looked into doing a google search..?

Comment: You can use [this](http://www.webappers.com/2008/07/07/jgrowl-unobtrusive-notification-system-for-jquery/) and apply AJAX in the `close` event handler to notify the server.

Comment: Shadow Wizard, jGrowl would be a nice choise but problem is that it can be positioned on corners only. I need to position it on specific place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for custom implementation of several technologies

- Use ajax request to call a web service and read your messages. You can return either JSON or HTML here, whatever format you prefer.
- Update the DOM container with the request.
- Set on click event to call another ajax web service to mark message as read and return updated messages
- Update the DOM container with latest data.

You just need to create a mechanism and call few .asmx web services from your ajax. Organize your code like that. If you are fluent in ASP.NET, javascript and ajax, then you will have no problems doing this.

Answer (score 0):

[JQuery with ASP.NET](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/Using-jQuery-with-ASP-NET.aspx)

Try this site.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid Page reload, bind the Data Using Get & Set Property in code behind.Create jquery Dynamically while first time page loading based on the get set property values.It will avoid page loading for every popup.

Use Ajax popups.or JQuert SlidDown and Hide. It will be useful more than Ajax.

U just need to plan clealy before writing a code.

Have u looked in google..?

http://jquery.com/

http://www.learningjquery.com/

http://jqueryui.com/

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

http://jquery.org/

Hope this may Helpful...